# Trying to move text box up after choosing selection of the combo box - MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox

I have a combo box that has different options and makes the text boxes visible when chosen. My issue with it is the bottom two text boxes stay in place when I would like it to automatically move up if other text boxes above it disappear. I've tried looking up solutions but I don't think I'm using the right terminology for this. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to manage and hold the positions (sequence) of the textboxes.

Here is, for inspiration, an extended example rearranging buttons. It is from the module `Form_ModernBox.cls` from my project [VBA.ModernBox](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernBox).

It does a lot of things to get hold on which buttons to display and where. At the very end, the `Top` and `Left` properties of the buttons are set:

```vb
Private Sub SetButtonSequence()

' Arrange from one to four visible buttons and refresh their captions.

    ' Maximum count of enabled (visible) buttons including Help button.
    Const MaxButtonCount    As Long = 3 + 1
    ' First button index.
    Const FirstButton       As Long = 0
    ' Undefined result value for Help button and inactive buttons.
    Const MsgBoxResultNone  As Long = 0
    
    Dim WindowWidth         As Long
    Dim WindowExpand        As Long
    Dim WindowExtend        As Long
    Dim ActiveButtonCount   As Long
    Dim HelpButtonCount     As ButtonCount
    Dim ButtonIndex         As Long
    Dim LineCount           As Integer
    
    ' Fill array of localized captions.
    Call FillCaptions
    ' Fill array of button positions.
    Call FillPositions
    
    If HelpButton = vbMsgBoxHelpButton Then
        ' The Help button shall be displayed.
        HelpButtonCount = ButtonCount.Help
    End If
    
    ' Set captions and return values on active (visible) buttons.
    Select Case ButtonSequence
        Case vbAbortRetryIgnore
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.AbortRetryIgnore
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonAbort), VbMsgBoxResult.vbAbort)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 1) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonRetry), VbMsgBoxResult.vbRetry)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 2) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonIgnore), VbMsgBoxResult.vbIgnore)
            NoCancel = True
        Case vbOKCancel
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.OKCancel
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonOK), VbMsgBoxResult.vbOK)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 1) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonCancel), VbMsgBoxResult.vbCancel)
        Case vbOkOnly
            ' Note: Any click action (except Help) will result in Cancel.
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.OKOnly
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonOK), VbMsgBoxResult.vbCancel)
        Case vbRetryCancel
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.RetryCancel
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonTryAgain), VbMsgBoxResult.vbRetry)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 1) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonCancel), VbMsgBoxResult.vbCancel)
        Case vbYesNo
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.YesNo
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonYes), VbMsgBoxResult.vbYes)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 1) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonNo), VbMsgBoxResult.vbNo)
            NoCancel = True
        Case vbYesNoCancel
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.YesNoCancel
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonYes), VbMsgBoxResult.vbYes)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 1) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonNo), VbMsgBoxResult.vbNo)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 2) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonCancel), VbMsgBoxResult.vbCancel)
        Case Else
            ' Identical to OKOnly.
            ' Note: Any click action (except Help) will result in Cancel.
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.OKOnly
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonOK), VbMsgBoxResult.vbCancel)
    End Select
    
    ' Add a Help button at far right if requested.
    If HelpButtonCount = 1 Then
        HelpButtonIndex = ActiveButtonCount
        Buttons(HelpButtonIndex) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonHelp), MsgBoxResultNone)
        ActiveButtonCount = ActiveButtonCount + HelpButtonCount
    End If
    ' Reset remaining buttons.
    For ButtonIndex = ActiveButtonCount To MaxButtonCount - 1
        Buttons(ButtonIndex) = Array(False, vbNullString, MsgBoxResultNone)
    Next
    ' Set display status for all buttons.
    For ButtonIndex = FirstButton To MaxButtonCount - 1
        With Me("Button" & CStr(ButtonIndex))
            .Visible = Buttons(ButtonIndex)(ButtonProperty.Visible)
            .Caption = Buttons(ButtonIndex)(ButtonProperty.Caption)
        End With
    Next
    
    ' Expand the form to make room for multiple buttons.
    WindowExpand = Positions(ActiveButtonCount - 1) - Positions(FirstButton)
    WindowWidth = Me.WindowWidth + WindowExpand
    Me.Move Me.WindowLeft, Me.WindowTop, WindowWidth
   
    ' Remove form's close button for certain button combinations.
    If NoCancel = True Then
        Me!ButtonCancel.Enabled = False
    Else
        ' Reposition Cancel button and form's close button (picture).
        Me!ButtonCancel.Left = Me!ButtonCancel.Left + WindowExpand
        Me!PictureClose.Left = Me!PictureClose.Left + WindowExpand
        Me!PictureCloseActive.Left = Me!PictureCloseActive.Left + WindowExpand
        Me!PictureCloseInactive.Left = Me!PictureCloseInactive.Left + WindowExpand
        Me!BoxInactive.Left = Me!BoxInactive.Left + WindowExpand
    End If
    
    ' Extend the form to fit a supersized prompt.
    LineCount = PromptLineCount()
    If LineCount > 0 Then
        ' Extend the form and controls (except buttons) to
        ' make room for multiple prompt lines.
        WindowExtend = FormExtend(LineCount)
    End If
    ' Position active buttons.
    For ButtonIndex = FirstButton To ActiveButtonCount - 1
        With Me("Button" & CStr(ButtonIndex))
            .Left = Positions(ButtonIndex)
            .Top = .Top + WindowExtend
        End With
    Next
    
    ' Apply tab settings.
    Call SetDefaultButton
    
End Sub
```